# Error in running tomcat server for web application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, web-development-server, embedded-tomcat-7

I have installed tomcat server on my eclipse and started it but when i hit the url i am getting error. I have set the port number as 8080.

The error message is :
HTTP Status 404 - /Basic_Struts2_Ant/index.action

type Status report

message /Basic_Struts2_Ant/index.action

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.34

Comment: Have you corresponding mapping in your web.xml? And how it looks like?

Comment: Yes I have , even I am able to generate the war file but while running through tomcat server i am getting the error.

Comment: So please, provide it to us, and also url u are entering when error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the tomcat logs for any errors.
Also check if the application is deployed in the path specified in -Dwtp.deploy. You can find this property in the VM argument of the server.